# Hover effect with image as background

Tags: html, css, hover

I don't know if there is a way to accomplish this or not. I have an image

```
 <img src="images/thumb.png" />
```

These are the CSS property of that image

```
float:left;
border:solid 1px #dadada;
margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
padding:5px;
border-radius:4px;
-moz-transition: border 0.2s linear 0s;
```

Now what I want to add a hover effect, but this hover effect has an image as a background like so:

```
    border:solid 1px #888888;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background: url(images/video.png) no-repeat;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

My problem is that my background image in the hover effect is not showing on top of my image like I want to.

Any help will be appreciate it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the img element in a div, something like this:

```
<div class="background">
    <img src="images/thumb.png" />
</div>
```

Then you can apply the background image to the div element, instead of the img element on hover state.

Your css should look something like this:

```
img{
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px #dadada;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-transition: border 0.2s linear 0s;
}

img:hover{
    border:solid 1px #888888;
    opacity:0.4; /* You can remove this line*/
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
div.background{
    background: url(images/video.png) no-repeat;
    height: /* same as your img */
}
```

Comment: Could you share a link to the page where you are trying to implement the effect?

Comment: My theme is not live yet but here is an example of what I'm trying to simulate/copy [Kriesi](http://www.kriesi.at/themedemo/?theme=newscast). Thank you for your assistance. If you hover on the image next to the Hello World post.

Comment: I didn't realize that you are floating the image, thus the wrapping div element height is 0, try giving some height to the wrapping div, probably you want to give them the same height as the img. I'll update my post

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it using jQuery. All you have to do is specify `hoverImg=""` and the script does the rest automagically.

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg" hoverImg="http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg">

$('body').find('*[hoverImg]').each(function(index){
    $this = $(this)
    $this.wrap('<div>')     
    $this.parent().css('width',$this.width())  
    $this.parent().css('height',$this.width())
    $this.parent().css('background-image',"url(" + $this.attr('hoverImg')+")")
        $this.hover(function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',.01)    
        },function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',1)             
        })                    
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/

​

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. Here is a link to what I'm looking for [click here](http://www.kriesi.at/themedemo/?theme=newscast) hover over the Hello World post image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a jQuery related question, plus, this script is just, well, not good code.